# Silverlight and XNA: This purple square is ruining my life

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, xna

Please help me this issue has already taken an absurd amount of hours from my life already. So I ported my game from XNA to silverlight, but I can't get the .xaml code to work properly. There is this mysterious giant purple square that covers the screen and blocks the DrawingSurface that runs the game. This bug is mysterious and driving me absolutely insane, I still don't know where its coming from really. Below are different .xaml versions to illustrate what I mean:

Worse case is when I just have normal code that should work fine:

```
        <Grid   Background="white" x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
            <DrawingSurface x:Name="myDrawingSurface" Draw="myDrawingSurface_Draw" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="600" Width="800" />
        </Grid>
```

This produces a page which is just the game in the middle, completely and perfectly blocked by the purple square (I can't post more than 2 links, so I won't link the image, but I did for the later scenarios).

In this example I moved the drawing surface over enough that it doesn't cover the entire game drawscreen so you can see what I mean better:

```
    <Grid   Background="white" x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <DrawingSurface x:Name="myDrawingSurface" Draw="myDrawingSurface_Draw" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="600" Width="800" Margin="434,0,-434,0" />
    </Grid>
```

This produces this image: http://greygods.com/Silverlight3dApp3/purpleissue2.PNG

The best workaround I got was this .xaml code which essentially somehow moves the purple square out of the way, I have almost no idea why this works or where the purple screen is coming from still though:

```
<Grid   Background="white" x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="800*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <DrawingSurface x:Name="myDrawingSurface" Draw="myDrawingSurface_Draw" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="600" Width="800" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

This creates a page like this and seemingly fixes it: http://greygods.com/Silverlight3dApp3/purpleissue3.PNG

Now the thing is even though I have this work around that kinda works, I can't do any complicated nested control structures or anything, it always comes back (I wanted to do a viewport outside the grid so that it inlarges with the browser size, but the damn purple square came back). Any time I want to change the xaml code the damn purple square comes back. Please help me please.

Other hints:

-The canvas control object causes the same issue.

-Viewbox does not cause the issue (but can't seem to get keyboard focus).

**EDIT NEW INFO:**

Here is my entire xaml file that manages to work good enough that I can get a viewbox around the grid as well. The workaround's strategy is essentially to make a 0,0 row and column, and put your actual visuals not in that row/column I don't think you even need the row to have 0 too, just the column is enough but I put both in this example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Silverlight3dApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
    mc:Ignorable="d" >

    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
    <Grid   Background="white" x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="800" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                <RowDefinition Height="500" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <DrawingSurface x:Name="myDrawingSurface" Draw="myDrawingSurface_Draw" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="480" Width="800" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

This looks like what you would expect, my game running fine in a 480-800 window that is then stretched out to encompass the entire browser, its great.

Here is also my xaml.cs file too:

```
namespace Silverlight3dApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {

        Game1 game;
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gt;

        readonly TimeSpan TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond / 60);
        readonly TimeSpan MaxElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond / 60); //was / 10

        TimeSpan accumulatedTime;

        public MainPage()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();  
        }


        private void myDrawingSurface_Draw(object sender, DrawEventArgs e)
        {

            TimeSpan elapsedTime = e.DeltaTime;

            if (elapsedTime > MaxElapsedTime)
            {
                elapsedTime = MaxElapsedTime;
            }

            accumulatedTime += elapsedTime;

            while (accumulatedTime >= TargetElapsedTime)
            {
                game.Update(e);
                accumulatedTime -= TargetElapsedTime;
            }

            // Render scene

            game.Draw(e);
            e.InvalidateSurface();


        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.RenderMode != RenderMode.Hardware)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please activate enableGPUAcceleration=true on your Silverlight plugin settings, right click -> permissions -> select this game -> allow. Then refresh the page", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                game = new Game1();  
                game.Attach(LayoutRoot); //was LayoutRoot
                gt = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime();
                game.Initialize();  // Create game
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share more of your outer parents/objects? I can't for the life of me understand why it's there or how your "fix" manages to fix it. My guess is there's something else going on here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest I'm glad I'm not the only one COMPLETELY baffled by it. I actually found a workaround that manages to work for view port nesting as well, that I put in the OP with editing above. What do you mean by outer parents? Like in the xaml file (sorry I'm new to silverlight kinda)? I posted the entire xaml file that manages to work completely above too.

Comment: `What happens in game.Attach(LayoutRoot)`, or `game.Initialize`? Does that try and create something in 0,0 cell of grid?